# Using cookie to track unique page views and hyperlink clicks. What if I have 100 pages to track?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies

I'm trying to write a PHP script that tracks the number of views of a page and the number of clicks of a hyperlink on that page. And I need to track both "total" and "unique" views/clicks.

I have heard that using cookie is a more reliable way than using IP for this matter. But I'm not a PHP expert so I don't know how exactly big companies do this.

The method I can think of is that, taking the tracking of /page1/ (url rewrote from page1.php) for example, if a visitor does not have a cookie named `page1`, update both the values of "total views" and "unique views" in the database and executing the PHP code below.

```
setcookie('page1', 'non-clicked', time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/page1/');
```

And when the same visitor clicks on the hyperlink, update both the values of "total clicks" and "unique clicks" in the database and execute the PHP code below.

```
setcookie('page1', 'clicked', time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/page1/');
```

And if the same visitor visits the page again in the future, his/her behavior(s) will only be recorded in "total views" (and "total clicks").

However, here comes the problem, what if I have 100 pages that need to track views/clicks? Will I have to make each of my visitor store 100 cookies in his/her browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using a cookie is that you put a unique, identifying token in the cookie and use that to identify an individual instead of their ip address.

Don't store all the data you collect in the cookie. You still collect that on the server exactly the same as if you were doing your tracking based on ip address. You simply associate the data with the token from the cookie instead of with the ip address.

Comment: Thanks. Should I really let each of my visitors store 100 or even 1000 cookies in his/her browser (when I need to track 100 or even 1000 pages)?

Comment: @IanY. — No. You should store 1 cookie with the identifying token. The user's identity doesn't change from page to page, so the token doesn't change from page to page, so you don't need a different cookie for each page.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there is "identifying token" in cookie aside from the "name=value" pair. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The identifying token is the thing you generate to identify the user which you then set the as the value of the cookie.

Comment: Do you mean storing the data of all pages in one cookie and using something like regular expression to detect/update the data of a individual page?

Comment: No. Read the answer. I said you store the data on the server.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. That sounds viable. I will give it a try.

Comment: What @Quentin meant is that you should simply store only 1 value: ***A token of some sorts - IP or some unique String*** in the Cookie and then use this as a Key to identify the User-Data that is stored in the Database...

Comment: @Poiz I see. Thank you.

Comment: Don't store the IP address in the cookie. It makes using a cookie in the first place pointless and you get the worst of both worlds. Use a unique identifier.